# how can i use the responder inputsStatesAndRef in a corda transaction?

Tags: corda

I'm trying to build a corda application for training porpuses. In this application i need to transfer
some coins to a new owner, and the states that keeps these coins has to be unique, if you have a previous coin state you will need to evolve it. For example, if someone transfer to you 300 coins and you already have 200 you will evolve this state of 200 coins to a new one of 500.

I've already tried to create other subflows to get the responder inputs to the transaction but it didn't work. Bellow you guys can see my request and response flow without handling this situation that i asked above. Can you guys have an ideia of how can i handle this situation?

Thank you guys so much and sorry about some english issues that my text can have.

```
    @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    class CoinTransferFlow(var amount: Double, val newOwner: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
        companion object {
            object GENERATING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Generating transaction based on new BrunoCoin.")
            object VERIFYING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Verifying contract constraints.")
            object SIGNING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Signing transaction with our private key.")
            object GETTING_OTHER_SIGNATURES : ProgressTracker.Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature.") {
                override fun childProgressTracker() = CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()
            }

            object FINALISING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
                override fun childProgressTracker() = FinalityFlow.tracker()
            }

            fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(
                    GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
                    VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
                    SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
                    GETTING_OTHER_SIGNATURES,
                    FINALISING_TRANSACTION
            )
        }

        override val progressTracker = tracker()

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            val listMoneyStateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(BrunoCoinState::class.java).states

            val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

            progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
            var txBuilder = buildTransaction(listMoneyStateAndRef, notary)

            progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION

            txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

            progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION

            val signedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

            progressTracker.currentStep = GETTING_OTHER_SIGNATURES


            progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION

            val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(newOwner)
            otherPartySession.send(signedTransaction)
            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTransaction, setOf(otherPartySession)))
        }
```

```
    @InitiatedBy(CoinTransferFlow::class)
    class TransferResponderFlow(val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

        companion object {

            object VERIFYING_TRANSACTION : ProgressTracker.Step("Counterparty verifying contract constraints.")
            object  FINALISING_TRANSACTION :  ProgressTracker.Step("Counterparty finalising the transaction")

            fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(
                    VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
                    FINALISING_TRANSACTION
            )
        }
        override val progressTracker = tracker()

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

            fun verifyTx(sgdTx : SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                "O output precisa ser do tipo BrunoCoinState"  using (sgdTx.tx.outputStates[0] is BrunoCoinState)

                val bCoinState = sgdTx.tx.outputStates[0] as BrunoCoinState

                "O output2 precisa ser do tipo BrunoCoinTransferState" using (sgdTx.tx.outputStates[1] is BrunoCoinTransferState)

                val bCoinTransferState = sgdTx.tx.outputStates[1] as BrunoCoinTransferState

                "Os valores propostos na transação deve ser maior que 0" using (bCoinState.amount > 0
                        && bCoinTransferState.amount > 0)

                "Os valores propostos na transação e o valor enviados devem ser iguais" using (bCoinState.amount == bCoinTransferState.amount)
            }


            val sgdTx = otherPartySession.receive<SignedTransaction>().unwrap{ it }

            progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION

            verifyTx(sgdTx)

            progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION

            return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession/*, expectedTxId = txId*/))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

addInputState adds a referenced input:

```
/** Adds an input [StateRef] to the transaction. */
open fun addInputState(stateAndRef: StateAndRef<*>) = apply {
    checkNotary(stateAndRef)
    inputs.add(stateAndRef.ref)
    inputsWithTransactionState.add(stateAndRef)
    resolveStatePointers(stateAndRef.state)
    return this
}
```

See an example: https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/auction-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/flows/BidFlow.java#L70